# Is it recommend to use the previous state when toggling or the react change event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have made a change to the `onChange` callback to use the state rather than the change event from React. Is this change recommended and in line with conventions or is it better to use the event from React instead?

```
const Toggle: React.FC = () => {
  const { on, setOn } = useContext(AppContext);
  const isOn: boolean = on.key === 'on';

  const handleToggle = (checked: boolean) => {
    const key: string = checked ? 'on' : 'off';

    setOn(key);
  };

  return (
    <Toggle
      name="toggle"
      type="checkbox"
      checked={isOn}
      onChange={(e: any) => handleToggle(e.target.checked)} // before
      onChange={() => handleToggle(!isOn)}                  // after
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: First feels more reliable at first glance, but I don't know if it's actually an issue. Also, don't ever use `any` if you're using TypeScript, that defeats the purpose

Comment: Thanks! I had `e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>` before but changed it for the sake of simplifying the code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would use neither, assuming that `on` and `setOn` are the result of a `React.useState()` hook which supports [functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates). Instead, something like this:

```
onChange={() => setOn(oldValue => oldValue ? 'off' : 'on')}
```

Using the [functional update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) behavior avoids any kind of possible race conditions - for example, what if by some unlikely coincidence the user clicks the toggle twice rapidly before React has a chance to process state updates and re-render? The result of two (or more) rapid clicks could possibly give improper behavior - React would use the same value for updating state multiple times in a row, essentially causing multiple clicks to behave as one (toggling the input `on` but not `off` again) instead of properly toggling the input `on` and then `off` and then `on` etc.

Functional updates enqueue the updates to be processed in order, in such a way that each update is guaranteed to have access to the true, updated state that resulted from the *previous* update. So even if the user clicked the toggle input twice, three time, a dozen times in a microsecond, the input end state will be as expected.

Edit: [this example I put together](https://codesandbox.io/s/why-functional-updates-6zt4q4?file=/src/App.tsx) demonstrates why this is important and the impact it has. Look closely at the `onClick` handlers of the counter buttons, and note how they match the three possible approaches we have identified. When you click the "Trigger three rapid clicks on all counter buttons below" button, it does just that. But observe how *only* the functional update approach gives the proper end state for this situation - it increments by +3, because it was clicked three times, while the other two counters only increment by +1.

Comment: I use a reducer (`const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, startingState);`) to handle state in this app but I think what you posted would still apply there?

Comment: Ideally your reducer in this case would expose a simple “toggle” dispatch function that uses its own internal state to set the new state rather than relying on the value it was called with, for the same reasons I outline another. Otherwise, yes it is possible to use functional updates with a reducer but it’s a bit more non-standard.